# How does the backup-button works and how can I use this under Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, backup, hard-drive, deja-dup, button

Many external hard drives have a backup-button with a OTB function for backing up stuff. An example is the "Sharkoon Quickstore Portable".

So how does this button works?

Is there a vendor neutral standard?

Does it need a special driver?

How can I assign a action to this button? (For example start the deja-dup backup)

Comment: Is there a USB-harddrive available which supports this button under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a drive with a button like this but due to my transient state the drive is in storage (I feel like there's a joke to be had there) and I have never researched the button before. **What I'm about to say could be completely incorrect.**

If I were to guess what was going on, I'd say the drive consisted of three things:

- A USB hub controller
- A USB storage controller
- A simple USB HID device

You can check this with `lsusb` or `sudo lshw | less`.

The hub and storage device will be as standard as possible so that anything can use them. The HID button might work in Linux without a driver but it won't be connected up to any known event.  If it does automatically work, it should have registered a device in `/dev/input/`. If that's a case, it's *fairly* simple to hook an event around it.

If there *isn't* a device registered automatically, it might be a very non-standard USB device that *needs* a custom driver for itself. I can't help you past this stage.

In Windows, you would install some software that would likely include the driver for the HID device, add a listener and tie the lot together.

Comment: lsusb gives me:

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 14cd:6116 Super Top

and sudo lshw | less doesn't show up anything useful

also there is no entry in /dev/input/

is there any usb debuging util?

Comment: Ok I tried https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/USB but no success...

Comment: @Sebastian is that the only new USB device shown in `lsusb` when you plug it in?

Comment: Yes did lsusb > test1 and lsusb > test2 after unplugging and the Line above was the diff...